# Are the correlations of multivariate stock prices preserved when converted to multivariate returns?

Tags: market-data, correlation, price, asset-returns, multivariate

If data for multiple stock prices has a specific correlation matrix, is the correlation matrix preserved when those prices are converted to multivariate log-differenced returns?

Comment: Hi: No. The return is (approximately ) the first difference of the log price and there's no theory that says that taking the log and differencing preserves correlations. In fact, the reason why such a transformation is used is to induce approximate stationarity. Prices themselves are not stationary so it's not a good idea to use them when doing econometric type analysis.

Comment: i ask because i know how to generate correlated GBM prices, and i know how to generate correlated random (non-GBM) returns, but as you can see, the latter, if converted to prices, will not display desired GBM behavior

Comment: The relationship between price and log-return correlation for GBM is derived in https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/45881/8153

Comment: good i saw that when u first put it here, but the question is about *targeting* those moments during generation of the gbm, not their relationship